# Why is .elasticbeanstalk folder included in .gitignore?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After I configured eb cli for my project, it seems to have automatically added it's configuration, saved in `.elasticbeanstalk` folder, to `.gitignore` file of my project. However, when I checked out the `config.yaml` (the only file in this folder) it didn't seem to contain any passwords or authentication information, just general configuration.

What's the rationale behind including it in the `.gitignore`? Wouldn't I want to track this information as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`config.yaml` is a pretty lightweight file but there are a couple of options unique to the local environment and developer which you would not want getting changed in a group development setting.

**They are:**

- default_ec2_keyname
- profile

`default_ec2_keyname`

This lets `eb` know what security key pair to use when deploying code. In a well structured security environment every developer would have their own set of credentials (uniquely named) and if this value was tracked and changes as a result it would cause problems

`profile`

This option is used as a shortcut to make using many sets of keys (even for one developer locally) easier to apply. For example: say I have 10 clients I do work for, each client has their own AWS account and delivers me my security key pairs. Locally I assign them each to a `profile` with a nickname so it easier to apply them to multiple repos, and so when I make a change to the profile credentials, that change is applied to all projects using that profile. (So if I have 10 repos for client_1 profile and client_1 cycles my deploy credentials, I only have to update them in one place, not in all 10 repos.)